# Plotting geopandas changes figure size in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, size, geopandas, figure

So I create a matplotlib figure, and then add 3 (germany, slovakia, czech) countries via shape files.

I explictly set the figsize as `(15, 15)`. `germany`, `czech`, `slovakia` are the read shape files, and finally `germany_pipe` is a `GeoDataFrame` which adds blue lines to the `matplotlib` figure.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(15, 15))

germany.plot(ax=ax, color='lightgray', edgecolor='white')

germany_pipe.plot(ax=ax, color='cornflowerblue',
                  linewidth=germany_pipe['diameter'].values/400)

czech.plot(ax=ax, color='lightgray', edgecolor='white')
slovakia.plot(ax=ax, color='lightgray', edgecolor='white')
```

After this figure looks like the following pic:

[image: fig1]

Then I plot also an other `GeoDataFrame`, which plots the other lines as red via: `data_geo.plot(ax=ax, color='red', linewidth=data_geo['diameter'].values/400)`

However after this point, the matplotlib figure changes size for some reason. **Do you know what is the reason for that?**

[image: fig2]

```
print(data_geo.crs)
None
print(germany_pipe.crs)
epsg:4326
```

Comment: Please show the output of these: `germany.crs`, `data_geo.crs`. Are they the same?

Comment: @swatchai I add them to the question

Comment: wow after I set `data_geo.crs = 'epsg:4326'`, it worked please write an answer and I will accept! @swatchai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotting several `geodataframes` on a common `ax` axis correctly requires all of them to have CRS (coordinate reference system) set properly. Preferably, all of them should have the same CRS for easy operation without (unnecessary) specifying coordinate transformation in the plotting instruction.

To read the CRS of a `gdf1` geodataframe, one can use:

```
gdf1.crs
```

And if you need to set a CRS (say, 'epsg:3395') to this geodataframe, you can do as follows.

```
gdf1.crs = 'epsg:3395'
```